# How to always have equally sized ticks in d3 scaleTime with dynamic time ranges

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an application that works with an xAxis that the user can configure, so the domain is dynamic and can range from an interval of years all the way down to seconds.

My issue lies with the fact that when I have a date ranging from e.g. 20 jan to 5 feb it has a number of ticks of equal size, except it always has a tick on 1 feb.

Is there a way I can avoid this extra tick from being generated?

Here's an example where it has an unwanted tick (1 February).

```js
const xScale = d3
    .scaleTime()
    .nice()
    .clamp(true)
    .domain([new Date(2000, 0, 20), new Date(2000, 1, 5)])
    .range([0, 500]);

const xAxis = d3.axisTop(xScale)
    .tickSize(1);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 600)
    .attr("height", 100);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0, 20)")
      .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```